# Tomcat 7 not working with Eclipse Luna in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: jsp, tomcat, tomcat7

Installed Ubuntu 14.04, installed Eclipse Luna, Installed tomcat 7. Added the Tomcat server in Eclipse server preference.

Now, tomcat doesn't ran several times stating that" port 8080 already in use". **Solved it temporarily** by killing the **tcp6 service** that was running on that port.

Created a simple project with just one "index.jsp" page. When selected "Run on server", it says that "**Selection doesn't contain any resources that can be run on a server**.

Is there anything else i have to install on my fresh installed Eclipse for running .jsp? Hibernate works fine though.

Answer (score 1):

I think for a jsp to run on tomcat you need at least a Dynamic Web Project. Try that using all defaults, make sure that you select the "Create web.xml deployment descriptor", put your index.jsp under WebContent, and Run on Server...